# drawbacks of a void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, void

A far as I know, a void pointer in C++ `void*` can point to anything. This might be quite useful (for me) if I want to develop a solution without using some sort of inheritance. But the question I want to know is whether there is any performance drawbacks in this approach?

Comment: What performance drawbacks? It is just a pointer like pointer to other types. From the description of your implementation seems you are trying to solve a C++ problem using C ways, which you should not. If you want inheritance use inheritance not `void *`.

Comment: The main trouble is figuring out what it actually does point to in order to correctly cast it back.  And if you get that wrong, you're lucky if you notice the bugs right away.

Comment: There won't be performance drawbacks, but you lose all type information (and thus type safety). This means the compiler won't be able to spot errors it could otherwise, and you will encounter them at runtime instead (think undefined bejaviour and hard-to-track bugs).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance drawbacks. The biggest drawback is that pretty much anything you do with a `void*` will give you undefined behaviour. I think the only defined use of a `void*` is to cast it back to point at the correct type.

Comment: There can easily be performance drawbacks.  At some point you have to figure out what the type of the `void*` actually is before using it (unless you are using it as an `intptr_t`).  If the type was already encoded in the program, that step would not be required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The biggest drawback is that making use of void pointers stops the compiler from being able to enforce type checking. Especially in a language that supports object oriented principles, I think it would be strange to be making heavy use of void pointers.

You are more likely to find void pointers in C to mimic some polymorphic behavior, but the same type-safety concerns exist.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the compiler's point of view

Answer (score 5):

There are two serious performance drawbacks of `void*`.  The
first is that it makes it far more difficult to understand and
maintain the program, which has a serious impact on the
performance of the maintenance programmers—and on
run-time, since it makes reworking the software more difficult
when the profiler shows where you have performance problems.
The fastest programs are the ones that are well written first,
since it then becomes possible to make local optimizations in
the critical places without having to rewrite the entire
program.

The second performance impact is that a `void*` can alias
anything.  Proper aliasing analysis is an important part of
compiler optimization, and anything you do to make this more
difficult hinders the optimizer, and can result in slower code.
(`char*` and `unsigned char*` have a similar effect.)

Comment: +1 for reframing the obvious issue as performance problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is no performance drawback when using a `void*` other than the fact that the compiler can't make assumptions about the type it points at. It is still a pointer like any other.

A `void*` was useful in C for pointing to any arbitrary type because any pointer to object type can be converted to a `void*`. However, doing pretty much anything with it will result in undefined behaviour. You can only safely cast it back to the original pointer type.

However, in C++ we have a much better way of storing a pointer to some arbitrary type - templates. For some template argument `T`, we can have a `T*`.

Comment: `Correct` may be correct but not useful. I would use the word `same` or `original`.

Comment: +5 for saying about **templates** .

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can have some performance drawbacks. By using `void *` you may disable optimization based on strict aliasing assumption.

Example

```
void fun(void * param1, int & param2)
{
    param2 = 7; // 1
    // do something with param1, param2 not used
    param2 += 1; // 2
}
```

If there was no `void *` variable, compiler might remove assignment 1 and in 2 just generate `param2 = 8`. But now it can't, because `param1` may point to `param2`, if you called `fun(&i, i)`.

[More about strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)

Comment: You probably meant *do something with param2, param1 not used*

Comment: No. I meant what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

> `void*` can point to anything. This might be quite useful (for me) if I want to develop a solution without using some sort of inheritance

If you are thinking about passing a `void*` pointer to some function, think already about the way it will be used. In order to invoke a method on this object or access its members, you need to know the type of that object anyway.

Use `void*` only if you really have to. If you are looking for a way how to treat objects in more generic way, then just go for proper OO design. When you have a `void*` pointer, the only thing you know is that *"there is something at this address in the memory"*, nothing more.

Performance of using `void*` pointers is same as with any other pointers. **Safety**, **understandability** and also with it related **extensibility** and **maintainability** of your code should be your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

There may still exist platforms where a `void*` is larger than other types of pointers, or have a different format so a cast to or from `void*` is turned into actual conversion code. On common (x86, ARM) hardware, that is not the case, so there are no performance problems with `void*` -- you're just giving up type safety.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why there'd be any performance issues when using a void pointer as opposed to any other kind of pointer. I would be more concerned with safety, which you are giving up with a void pointer.